# dump1090 offline raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, offline, software-defined-radio

I'm currently doing a project in which I'm making an ADS-B flightradar on a led matrix, which is controlled by a Raspberry Pi. I've found a program called dump1090 which receives and decodes the data from my SDR receiver. I can find lots of example on how to use to forward that data to a webserver or whatever, but I can't seem to find anything on how you can programmatically listen to the data dump1090 produces. Does anyone know how you can programmatically receive dump1090's data in order to use the data in a program? (any language would do, but perhaps python would be the most obvious choice)

Comment: by the way, have a look at gr-air-modes, which implements its own transponder decoder and has a pretty python API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to start dump1090 using a programming language of choice (c/c++/java/python/etc.) and and read the `std out` pipe.

Personally, on Raspberry Pi, I find Python nicer to use since it's easier to test/reiterate without needing to compile. Python provides the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) package which allows you run dump1090(or any other application) from within Python and have a look at the output (using `subprocess.check_output('dump1090')` for example). Have a look at `check_output` and `Popen` options to see what works best with your application.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for helping me out here